# Calculate the average of the listed elements ine the list

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists:

1. with the elements: `[0.7181,7.3,561257621.7,0.12122,9.8]`
2. with indices:`[0,2]`

How can I calculate average of elements which indices I do have in second table?

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Comment: please read about [indexing in Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: So I can create the additional table and append it with the items with the maching indices. But I am looking for faster way.

Comment: `numpy.mean(numpy.array(elements)[indices])`

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
>>> elements = [0.7181, 7.3, 561257621.7, 0.12122, 9.8]
>>> indices = [0, 2]
>>> sum([elements[i] for i in indices])/len(indices)
280628811.20905
```